# HTML5 time and schema startDate

Tags: schema.org, html

Is there any way I can combine the `<meta />` and `<time />` together? Are they both necessary?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
      <a itemprop="url" href="nba-miami-philidelphia-game3.html" itemprop="name"> 
            Miami Heat at Philadelphia 76ers
      </a>

      <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-04-21T20:00">
      <time datetime="2016-04-21T20:00"></time>
        Thu, 04/21/16
        8:00 p.m.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you do:

```
<time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2016-04-21T20:00">
    Thu, 04/21/16
    8:00 p.m.</time>
```

Have a look at the date examples in the [basic syntax section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html#the-basic-syntax).

Comment: @toutpt What official documentation are you referring to?  The example comes directly from the spec.

Comment: @toutpt Those examples aren't using the `time` element, none of them conflict with this example

Comment: Oh yes, they use the span tag. sorry @robertc

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to meet both HTML5 and Schema.org/RDFA Lite, you can do this:

```
<time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2016-04-21T20:00" content="2016-04-21T20:00">Thu, 04/21/16 8:00 p.m.</time>
```

Parsing of ISO Dates is way easier than dealing with the text representation